# How do `mtpfs` and `jmtpfs` differs?

Tags: mtp

For mounting an Android device, one may use `mtpfs` or `jmtpfs` and both seems to do the same.

How do both differs?

Comment: Is this related to Ubuntu? See [similar question in Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304438/whats-the-difference-between-mtpfs-and-jmtpfs-packages-in-debian)

Comment: Yes, thanks, it answered my question. But seems I can’t close my duplicate.